# Reduce number of preflight requests for Azure Storage Services Rest API

Tags: azure, cors, azure-blob-storage, preflight, vary

I am uploading my files in Azure Blob Storage using [Azure Blob Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices). I break my file in multiple chunks and upload all chunks 1 by 1 using [Put Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block) rest API. At times if a file is over 1 GB, I have to make more than 100 API calls to completely upload a file.

I have noticed that before every API call, a preflight request is sent by the browser. I have set "Access-Control-Max-Age" header to 3600, but chrome continue to ignore it.

After some research, I found out that browsers don't cache response for put requests, and [Put Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block) rest API is actually a PUT request, that is why a preflight request is made before every call.

Is there a work around for this problem? Sending a preflight request before every call is too expensive and has a hit on performance.

Comment: what is it set for `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` ?

Comment: @Thomas It is set to '*'